# Depletion Region of PN junction

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In the depletion region of the PN junction diode, charge carriers are negligible but there is charge density. How?

Comment: The mobile charge carriers are negligible but the immobile charge from the ionized donor and acceptors has a charge density.

Comment: In each of P and N materials alone, there originally should have some charge carriers to be neutral, to have no charge density. The missing charge carriers at the PN junction necessarily means that there are some opposite charges.